# I am storing identity value of one table to another table in the foreign key but when make relationship it gives me error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

I am storing identity value of one table to another table in the foreign key but when trying to create a relationship, I get an error 332.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[spRegisterUser]
    @Doj date,
    @UserName nvarchar(100),
    @Password nvarchar(10),
    @Reference nvarchar(50),
    @Aadhar nvarchar(50),
    @Email nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    Declare @count int
    Declare @ReturnCode int

    Select @count = COUNT(UserName)
    from tblUsers where UserName = @UserName
    if @count > 0
    Begin
        Set @ReturnCode = -1
    End
    Else
    Begin   
        Set @ReturnCode = 1 

        insert into tblUsers (DoJ,UserName,Password,Reference,Aadhar,Email) 
        Output inserted.User_ID into tblUserProfiles(UserID)
        values (@DoJ,@UserName,@Password,@Reference,@Aadhar,@Email)
    End
    Select @ReturnCode as ReturnValue
end
```

Error is:

> The target table 'tblUserProfiles' of the OUTPUT INTO clause cannot be on either side of a (primary key, foreign key) relationship. Found reference constraint 'FK_tblUserProfiles_tblUsers'.

How to overcome this problem? I need PK FK relationship and I also want FK value automatically saved in the column.

Please find a solution for me. Thanks

Comment: How about some codes ? How do you create your database ? Without that information, it's impossible to find out the error.

Comment: you are inserting a single record. There is no reason to use the output clause altogether. Just use a variable to hold the @@SCOPE_IDENTITY and you are good

Comment: @cha . . . That is really, really, really bad advice.  The right way to return ids from an `insert` is how the OP is doing it, using `OUTPUT`.

Comment: @rahul  . . . I would suggest putting the value in a table variable first, and then loading the data from there into the final table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff why is it such a bad advice to use `scope_identity()` in this case? I understand the need for output clause when inserting multiple records, but when inserting a single record why not use `scope_identity()`?

Answer (score 0):

Since this stored procedure is really only ever inserting **one** single row of data, you could use this code:

```
declare @NewUserID INT

insert into tblUsers (DoJ, UserName, Password, Reference, Aadhar, Email) 
values (@DoJ, @UserName, @Password, @Reference, @Aadhar, @Email);

-- get the newly created ID for the new user
SELECT @NewUserID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

-- insert into the other table
INSERT INTO dbo.tblUserProfiles (UserID)
VALUES (@NewUserID);
```

This assumes that the `User_ID` column in the `tblUsers` table is in fact an **Identity** column.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use a trigger for insert on the users table, that will insert records into the user profiles table whenever they are inserted into the users table. The advantage of this approach is that even if users are inserted directly to your table (I mean, not using your stored procedure), they will still have a record created in the user profiles table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tblUsers_INSERT ON tblUsers 
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tblUserProfiles(UserId)
    SELECT User_ID 
    FROM Inserted

END
```